# Run uninstall.php if a checkbox is checked from settings page

Tags: plugin-development

I am building a custom plugin and when the plugin is activated it creates 2 tables inside the wp database. What I want is, to add a checkbox is my custom plugin settings page, and if the checkbox is checked, the tables to be deleted from the database. I am using and uninstall.php file to delete my tables but that happens when I delete the plugin. I would like to fire that uninstall.php file which have the scripts to delete my tables, if the checkbox is checked.

Here is my code

```
<form action="options.php" method="POST" id="my-form">
<?php
    settings_fields("customfields");
    do_settings_sections("support");
    submit_button("Save Data");
    ?>
</form>
<p>Delete Database? <?php echo get_option("delete_database"); ?></p>
<?php
add_settings_section("section", null, null, "support");
add_settings_field("wp_delete_database", "Delete Database?", array($this, "HTML"), "support", "section");
register_setting("customfields", "wp_delete_database", array("sanitize_callback" => "sanitize_text_field", "default" => "Placeholder"));
?>
```

Comment: Inside uninstall.php just check `get_option( 'delete_database' );` before doing anything.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thank you for ur reply. Can you give me a code example?

Answer (score 3):

You should have a function (single class, or method in a class) for the task to remove all the data from the plugin, like database or options entries.

On your settings page, call after an active checkbox this function, after sending a request, like via Button. In the `uninstall.php` have you also the possibility to use this function.

So you have only one function to do the same goal and no redundancy.

#### `register_uninstall_hook`

For the un-installion of the plugin via Core Function, Gui in the admin backend use the function [`register_uninstall_hook`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_uninstall_hook/).

#### The `uninstall.php`

could look like this

```php
<?php
/**
* Uninstallation script
* This file is called automatically by WP when the admin deletes the plugin from the installation.
*/
    
! defined( 'WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN' ) && exit;

require_once __DIR__ . '/src/settings.php';
// Use core function to delete items in the options table
delete_site_option( Your_Class_Settings::OPTION_NAME );
// Call method from class
Your_Class_Settings->uninstall();
```